# как отправить сообщение вк через python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

У меня есть код:

```
import vk_api

mytoken = 'мой токен'
session = vk_api.VkApi(token=mytoken)
vk = session.get_api()

def send(msg):
    vk.messages.send(user_id=айди человека, message='сообщение', random_id=0)
```

После запуска кода ничего происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где была допущена ошибка в коде?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def auth_handler():
    """ При двухфакторной аутентификации вызывается эта функция.
    """

    # Код двухфакторной аутентификации
    key = input("Enter authentication code: ")
    # Если: True - сохранить, False - не сохранять.
    remember_device = True

    return key, remember_device


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(
    <login>,
    <password>,
    auth_handler=auth_handler,
    config_filename='vk_config.v2.json'
)
vk_session.auth()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def send(msg):
    vk.messages.send(user_id=айди человека, message='сообщение', random_id=0)
```

заменить 'user_id' на 'peer_id'